# How to show count down timer on cell in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

** I show count down timer on cell when i long press on cell.but the problem is that when i click on row timer started but suddenly when i click on second cell timer stop of previous cell and start timer new cell which i click ,but the main functionality which i need is that i have to show running previous timer and current timer . please any one give me right way for that.**

```
 -(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
 { AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:ChatTable];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [ChatTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];


if ([[[userArray valueForKey:@"sender_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString: app.userId]) {

}

else{

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {

        if ([imageCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]==NULL) {

        }
        else
        {
            self.picId=[[userArray valueForKey:@"pic_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            self.imageName=[[userArray valueForKey:@"imagename"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            ChatTable.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            // self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
            image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
            self.pickerValue=[[userArray valueForKey:@"seconds"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            image.image=[imageCache objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
            [self.view addSubview:image];
            [self showTableTime:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UITableViewCell * myCell = [ChatTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpathForTimer];
        UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *)[myCell viewWithTag:101];
        myLabel.text=@"";
        //  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
        [image removeFromSuperview];
    }

}

}

-(void)showTableTime:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  secondsLeft=[self.pickerValue integerValue];
   indexpathForTimer=indexPath;
   [self countDownTimer];

 }

- (void)countDownTimer {

  timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self           selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

   }
   - (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {

UITableViewCell * myCell = [ChatTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpathForTimer];
UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *)[myCell viewWithTag:101];
if (secondsLeft >0) {
    secondsLeft --;
    UILabel * myLabel = (UILabel *)[myCell viewWithTag:101];
    myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",secondsLeft];

}
else if(secondsLeft==0)
{
    [self.image removeFromSuperview];
    [timer invalidate];
    ChatTable.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    myLabel.text=@"";
    [self SendRequsetToServerOfSeenImage];

}
else
{
}


}
```

Comment: i want to implement same to run multiple timer have you done it successfully ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only store one timer/indexpath pair (you only use the variables "timer" and "indexPathForTimer"). As soon as you activate a second cell, the variable indexPathForTimer will be overwritten with the indexPath for the second cell, so you only update the second cell.

I would suggest you convert the variable timer into an NSMutableArray and indexPathForTimer into an NSMapTable and then do

```
// code to init the map table, perform this where you initialize your variables
// (you may want to use weakToStrong or weakToWeak depending on your memory
// management)
indexPathForTimer = [NSMapTable strongToStrongObjectsMapTable];

// use this code to create your timer instance with reference to the index path
// for which it was instantiated
NSTimer* newTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimerInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer addObject:newTimer];
[indexPathForTimer addObject:indexPath forKey:newTimer];
[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:newTimer forModes:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

In your updateCounter: method, you can then get the real index path like so

```
currentIndexPath = [indexPathForTimer objectForKey:theTimer];
```

Comment: [__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2c9000
2013-04-04 13:12:39.604 SnapChat[996:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa2c9000'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that NSMutableDictionary requires NSCopying. I updated the code to use a map table.

Comment: [indexPathForTimer addObject:indexPath forKey:newTimer];  indexPathForTimer is dictionary i am not able to addobject in dictionary ,when i apply the code     [indexPathForDictionaryTimer setObject:indexPath forKey:newTimer]; its giving warning please help me

Comment: i apply your logic by change this line     [indexPathForDictionaryTimer setObject:indexPath forKey:newTimer];
but previous cell stuck and new cell get started by this code please tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)countDownTimer 
{

timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self           selector:@selector(updateCounter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

 }
```

Comment: i try this but previous timer stop on current position and second cell timer get started .

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run multiple timer on view or on each cell. but it become complicated to handle multiple timers that running on different cells.